# A reliable way to detect systemd

Tags: c, linux, daemon, systemd

Is this a reliable way to detect if a daemon was started from systemd?

```
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h> 
#include <unistd.h>   

bool DetectSystemd(void)
{
    if (sd_booted() > 0 && getppid() == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an XY problem to me. I can imagine two reasons why you might be caring:

1. You want to know whether to run your program in foreground mode or daemon mode.
2. You rely (possibly optionally) on systemd services.

Defining "daemonize" as "(double) fork and exit the parent to be reparented to init, as well as taking care of other steps such as giving up the controlling terminal, ..." (Edit: the systemd maintainers have written a handy man page: [`daemon(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/daemon.7.html) (not to be confused with `daemon(3)`, which is not useful)

A traditional daemon would take a command-line option: either --daemonize (if the default is to run in the foreground) or --foreground (if the default is to daemonize). The responsibility to pass one of those flags belongs to whoever started the program (if a user) or whoever wrote the init script (which should be the *packager*, not you the upstream).

The trend in modern practice has changed: processes should not take care of themselves, but are run by a daemon manager, such as start-stop-daemon(8) (again, a decision of the packager).

Now that systemd is becoming ubiquitous, some of the best practices are changing. For example, it is now possible for the upstream to ship one .service file instead of each packager having to ship their own variant, and it is now completely pointless to implement the daemonization steps on your own.

For the second case, if you want to use some of systemd's services - just try to use them, and check for errors like you always should. For many applications you wouldn't yet want to make it a hard error (there should probably be *some* way to run your program without systemd, if only for development/testing - but this could require changing some config option, it doesn't have to be easy), but a hard dependency is becoming legitimate now.